# PHP: How to Sort by Last Name & Distance of a Database

Tags: php, html, database, sorting

I am having trouble figuring it out.  I am probably just overlooking it but, I'd figure someone could give me a hand as to what to do.  I need to sort by last name and by the distance with the click of two separate radio buttons.  This is all due in an hour and a half and I am new to sorting with PHP.  I have searched on here but I did not find any answers pertaining to what I was looking for.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PHP:

```
<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Distance</th></tr>
    <?php  
    include('includes/database/dbc.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM runner ORDER BY 'lname'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error! '.mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
    echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>Sorry, no lists are available today. Check back soon!</td></tr>";
    }
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['fname'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'    .$row['lname'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'    .$row['email'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'    .$row['Distance'].'</td></tr>';
    }
    ?>
    <?php if(isset($_POST['submit_sort'])){
    $radio = $_POST['submit_sort'];
    if($radio =='fname'){
        $select ="SELECT fname, address1 FROM runner ORDER BY lname";}elseif($radio =='address1'){
        $select ="SELECT fname, address1 FROM runner ORDER BY address1";}       
    $result = mysql_query($lrconnect,$select)or die("Invalid query: ".mysql_error($lrconnect));
    }
    ?>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sort">
        <form class="form2" action="submit_sort">
            <input type="radio" name="sort" value="lname" id="lnamesort" >Sort By Last Name
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="sort" value="distance" id="distancesort">Sort By Distance
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens currently? Quotes are for strings, backticks are for escaping. Your select query is the same, I'd define the query then append the column to order by to the end of query.

Comment: Currently, nothing is happening.  The whole thing just doesn't function at all for me.

Comment: So it is a white page? Check the error logs. Also form is `GET` if `POST` isn't specified.

Comment: There is mistakes in your code for condition you have used for check current option submit_sort insted of sort and also in your sql query you have used order by address1 insted of distance.

Comment: Chris85, I get a normal page without error logs.  Just nothing appears to work with it.  Each radio clicked does absolutely nothing.

Comment: `submit_sort` loads though?

Comment: Lalji Nakum, I fixed what you mentioned and still nothing is working for me.  Once I click on a button, nothing gets sorted.

Comment: yes submit_sort loads but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

There is some mistakes in your code. It should be like below according to your needs:

HTML:-

```
 <div id="sort">
            <form class="form2" action="your_action" method="POST">
                <input type="radio" name="sort" value="lname" id="lnamesort" >Sort By Last Name
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="sort" value="distance" id="distancesort">Sort By Distance
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="search">
            </form>
    </div>
```

PHP:-

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['sort'])){
    $radio = $_POST['sort'];
    if($radio =='lname'){
        $select ="SELECT fname, address1 FROM runner ORDER BY lname";
    }elseif($radio =='distance'){
        $select ="SELECT fname, address1 FROM runner ORDER BY distance";
    }       
    $result = mysql_query($lrconnect,$select)or die("Invalid query: ".mysql_error($lrconnect));
}
?>
```

Comment: It would be great if you explain the mistakes and the modifications that you have done

Comment: 1) there was no post method and no submit button in form. 2) There was no proper conditions while comparing in PHP.

Comment: I am to not use a submit button though.  It's suppose to automatically sort the database by last name with one radio button and the other is suppose to sort by distance.

Comment: I figured it out.  Thank you all for helping!  It was a small error at the end of the PHP file as well causing nothing to work.  It works now.  Thanks again everybody!